# How to generate OTRS-Tickets using the OTRS REST-Interface

Tags: otrs

From where to get the api key. I am using trail version of OTSR. How to get Api key for this

Answer (score 1):

From where do you get the info that you need an API key? Login credentials or a valid session id are sufficient.